# Drilldown displayed in column instead of pie chart

Tags: highcharts

I am very new to UI. I am trying to display data in a pie chart format using Highchart.

I am able to get the first chart in pie format but when I go for a drilldown, it turns out in column.

```
Below is the fiddle link:
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/uk7sqy3e/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the type in the `drilldownJson` variable:

```
var drilldownJson = '[{...,"type":"pie","color":"#FFF000","data":[...]}]';
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1p3bhdqc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.type

Comment: I figured that out.. what I did is enclosed it in the scope and removed the type. Not sure if that is right. Thanks for the info though.